# Horner's method using recursion in java with 2 parameters

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, math

[image: Horners method]

Hello, everyone. My current university assignment is to represent [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) using recursion. Before this task we had to do it with a loop, which was easy. But I have no idea how to do this using recursion with only 2 parameters which cannot be changed.

```
public static double evalHornerRec(double[] a, double x)
```

This is the function i have to use

```
   private static int horner(int a[], int x, int n){
            int h;
            if(n>0)
                h=horner(a, x, n-1);
            else
                return a[n];
 
            return h*x+a[n];
     }
```

I found something like this  but it has 3 parameters and not 2

Comment: Perhaps instead of passing n, chop off the head of your array and pass the chopped array down the recursion?

Comment: The function `horner` you have is already recursive.

Comment: The number of arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use *two-args* method, you can call the method containing the actual recursive logic, providing the `0` (the first index of the given array) as the third argument.

**Note** that the *base case* of the recursion is when we're hitting the last element ***a<sub>n</sub>***, i.e. when index `n` is equal to `a.length - 1`.

Otherwise, the call should be handled by the *recursive case*, containing the logic compliant with the Horner's rule.

```
public static double evalHornerRec(double[] a, double x) {
    
    return horner(a, x, 0);
}

private static double horner(double a[], double x, int n) {
    if (n == a.length - 1) return a[n];
    
    return a[n] + x * horner(a, x, n + 1);
}
```

Comment: I tried to submit this but theres an error. I think I am not allowed to use two functions for this, it has to be in the same one.

Comment: @yungboi22 Sorry, my fault, I've reversed the array. Fixed the bug. Try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comment, keep chopping the head off the poly array and pass the chopped version down the recursion call, like so ([this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method#Polynomial_evaluation_and_long_division) provides an illustration):

```java
public class Main {
    static int horner(int a[], int x) {
        switch (a.length) {
            case 1:  return a[0];
            default: return a[0] + x * horner(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length), x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 2x^3 - 6x^2 + 2x - 1 for x = 3 => 5
        int[] poly = {-1, 2, -6, 2};
        System.out.println(horner(poly, 3)); // 5
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth to note that due to the allocating a new copy of the array with each recursive call, this approach has quadratic time complexity **O(n^2)** and also requires additional **O(n^2)** space.

Comment: In the context of this particular exercise, why is this worth to note? Do you think that a recursive Java implementation of Horner in any shape or form is used outside of a homework scenario?

Comment: The point of coding challenges is usually to address the problem with the optimal solution (*in terms of time and space complexity*). Performance, matter in algorithmic exercises and in real-world programming. Hence, this information would be beneficial for future readers (*don't forget that OP is not the only person who take advance from the answers*).

Comment: Ah OK, future readers may want to have a look at an optimal solution (in terms of time and space complexity) like this one:

https://github.com/apache/commons-math/blob/3e72f1ea31f4b0ed43e6cb48381f86b95c15f36c/commons-math-legacy/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/math4/legacy/analysis/polynomials/PolynomialFunction.java#L121